# Want to introduce myself to someone I was provided a business card

Tags: word-order

I am searching for an Administrative Assistant/Clerical position and a friend of mine provided me with a business card of the Asst. Vice President of career service and alumni relations at a college. 
as I don't want to sound desperate but able to submit my resume for her to review it. how do I introduce myself and ask for her assistance?

Thank You
Sharlene

Comment: Alas, this site isn't the place for either career or specific writing advice.  That said, ask your friend if you may use her name as the person who suggested you get in touch the the Asst. VP.

Comment: This is not meant as any offense, but you displayed a number of grammar errors in your communication. I would recommend finding someone to help with your resume. The Stack Exchange Writer's Forum will be more receptive when you get that far.

Answer (score 0):

Call her and introduce yourself over the phone and reference the business card.  Or do the same in an email.  Once a chain of communication has been opened, getting your resume & cover letter looked at will be easier.